# Timescale Compressed table taking forever for simple queries

Tags: timescaledb

I have a hypertable with around 40 million rows. Was hoping to compress it to reduce some of our storage costs. Prior to compression, the following query runs super fast.

`select * from trades where pair = 'xxxxxxxxx';`

after compression, this query hangs for a very long time (30-40+s)

Looking at the query plan, it seems like it's decompressing every single chunk, then checking to see if the pair exists, and then moving to the next chunk if it doesn't. While it *SHOULD* be checking to see if the pair exists, and only decompressing the chunk if it does.

I have `segementby` set to pair, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing.

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
    "timestamp" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    tx varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pair varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    price float8 NOT NULL,
    amount float8 NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX trades_pair_timestamp_idx ON public.trades USING btree (pair, "timestamp" DESC);

SELECT create_hypertable('trades', 'timestamp');

alter table trades set (
  timescaledb.compress, 
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'pair',
  timescaledb.compress_orderby = 'timestamp');

SELECT add_compression_policy('trades', INTERVAL '1 week');
```

Comment: Note that your query requires to read all chunks, since the chunks can be excluded only on time column. Still since the column is in segmentby the decompression should not be required and @TDF pointed out a bug, which can be a reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Timescaledb are you running? [There was a bug](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3351) related to varchar fields not being filtered prior to decompression, which [has been fixed in 2.3.1](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/pull/3367)

Comment: I have never hated & loved someone simultaneously in my entire life. Have been spending hours on this. Thank you so much.